# Поиск похожих изображений

Tags: python, изображения

Задача - распознать одинаковые изображения, прогнанные через цепочку соц. сетей. В этом случае как минимум к исходнику может быть добавлена какая-либо плашка снизу, может быть добавлен вотермарк, изображение может быть несколько раз пережато в jpeg с довольно низким качеством (Особенности загрузки внутри соц. сетей).

В общем случае знаком с теорией и таким понятиями как pHash (phash.org), однако в чистом виде для моей задачи данный инструмент малоприменим. Хеш от оригинала и такой вот копии выходит слишком различным, что не дает возможности определить изображения как схожие.

Как вариант - разбивать изображения на более мелкие участки и пытаться сравнивать уже на основе их совпадений (Что, по идее, способно дать и возможность определять кропы от изображений), однако в этом случае встает вопрос об организации хранения подобных данных, плюс, насколько я понимаю, не спасет от проблем, связанных с артефактами при конвертации в jpeg низкого качества.

Гугление, как ни странно, особых результатов по этой теме не выдает, максимум, что удалось найти - [libpuzzle](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle), который, вроде как, использует больше алгоритмов выявления схожести, но при этом мне не удалось найти на него хоть сколь-нибудь вменяемую документацию, а в разумении сишного кода, я, к сожалению, не силен. [Питоновский биндинг](https://github.com/ArchangelSDY/PyPuzzle) не сильно помогает. Кроме того, в примерах я не обнаружил хеширования изображений, что делает весьма затруднительным поиск похожих среди распознанных ранее.

Возможно, сообщество сможет помочь и назвать готовые библиотеки, способные решить данную задачу? В дополнение к перечисленному в первом абзаце, библиотека должна уметь выдавать некий хеш, который возволял бы поиск схожих на основе заранее накопленной коллекции. Это вовсе не обязательно должно быть быстро (Обработка планируется не в real time), но при этом не должно занимать часы с полным перебором всех файлов заранее накопленных изображений.

Эти библиотеки должны иметь биндинг для python или, хотя бы, command line интерфейс, позволяющий использовать их через python.

Теоретические сведения по проблеме без библиотек тоже приветствуются, однако вряд ли смогут помочь, так как времени на написание собственной библиотеки нет, да и, боюсь, на подобный rocket science у меня просто не хватит квалификации, так как понимание темы весьма посредственное.

Comment: Слишком общая задача. По идее, это нужно сначала очистить изображение от вотермарков и прочих плашек, что само по себе не просто, кроме того, изображения могут быть пережаты движком соцсети, попиксельно они точно не совпадут никогда. В общем, всё упирается как обычно в определение - что такое "похожесть"? )

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поискать для питона что-нибудь по теме feature points (т.н. особенные точки изображения) и их классификации посредством машинного обучения. В OpenCV (фреймворк для задач компьютерного зрения) [имеется](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html) указанный инструментарий. Если не ошибаюсь, то к нему существует и обёртка для питона. Единственное, что стоит отметить, так это то, что представленный по приведённой ссылке пример не подходит для распознавания изображений, пусть и содержащих внешне схожие объекты. Это должно быть реально одно и тоже изображение, сравниваемая часть которого подверглась лишь некоторым преобразованиям, в основном геометрическим, либо если какую-то его часть добавили/убрали, на вроде водяного знака.

Comment: С некоторыми трудностями удалось проверить ваш пример. Для будущих поколений, аналогичный пример для python находится здесь: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html. С некоторыми изменениями мне удалось даже запустить его, результат для упрощения восприятия разместил на [github](https://github.com/izeleny/opencv_test). Тем не менее остались вопросы. Например вот результат SIFT сравнения двух изображений http://i.imgur.com/2sbcCxv.png - для условно идентичных изображений и http://i.imgur.com/h4MWF9F.png для различных.

Comment: False positive крайне нежелателен, а более-менее четко понять, сколько пересечений должно присутствовать для его отсеивания на данных мне не удалось. Кроме того, насколько я понимаю, нельзя получить некий хеш для предварительной оценки и при добавлении нового изображения придется перебирать всю коллекцию (Сохранение дескрипторов тоже не сильно поможет, так как это списки из десятков тысяч значений). Для моей задачи это недопустимо, так как коллекция, условно, может состоять из нескольких тысяч изображений, перебирать которые каждый раз будет крайне накладным. В любом случае благодарю за ответ!

Comment: В ответе я написал, что классификация особенных точек должна производиться при помощи распознавания заранее обученной машины. Непосредственное изъятие дескрипторов - это только пол-дела. На них необходимо обучить машину (если посмотреть описание класса того же FlannBasedMatcher, то можно найти соответствующие методы). Далее, классификатор сохраняется в файл на диске и загружается, когда нужно его использовать. Всё это работает очень быстро. Заново перебирать исходные изображение не требуется.

Answer (score 0):

тема интересная, в голову пришла идея: искать на изображении точки(области точек) конкретного цвета (которого в изображении меньше всего***) и вычислять между ними пропорции, на основе которых можно предположить, что изображения похожи друг на друга.

*** Предварительно можно конвертировать с определенным цветовым набором

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/726259)